# xml to html conversion using third party api

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

i am using a third party API and getting a data in xml form. how can i convert this data into html file.
i am new to web services
i tried to write xslt file but i am not very sure of tags

```
  <Result>
        <Error>False</Error>
        <Total>8</Total>
        <Query>diabetes</Query>
        <Language>English</Language>
        <Topics Count="4">
            <Topic>
                <Id>14</Id>
                <Title>Get Your Cholesterol Checked</Title>
                <Categories>Screening Tests, Doctor Visits, Doctor Visits</Categories>
                <Populations />
                <MyHFTitle />
                <MyHFDescription />
                <MyHFCategory />
                <LastUpdate>2/18/2014 9:33:17 AM</LastUpdate>
                <ImageUrl>http://www.healthfinder.gov/HealthTopics/glmedia/icons/getyourcholesterolchecked.jpg</ImageUrl>
                <ImageAlt>smiling couple</ImageAlt>
                <AccessibleVersion>http://healthfinder.gov/HealthTopics/Category/doctor-visits/screening-tests/get-your-cholesterol-checked</AccessibleVersion>
                <RelatedItems>
                    <Item>
                        <Title>Heart Healthy Foods: Shopping list</Title>
                        <Url>http://healthfinder.gov/HealthTopics/Category/health-conditions-and-diseases/heart-health/heart-healthy-foods-shopping-list</Url>
                        <Type>tool</Type>
                    </Item>
                    <Item>
                        <Title>Heart Health: Conversation starters</Title>
                        <Url>http://healthfinder.gov/HealthTopics/Category/health-conditions-and-diseases/heart-health/heart-health-conversation-starters</Url>
                        <Type>tool</Type>
                    </Item>
                    <Item>
                        <Title>Reduce Your Risk of Stroke</Title>
                        <Url>http://healthfinder.gov/HealthTopics/Category/health-conditions-and-diseases/heart-health/reduce-your-risk-of-stroke</Url>
                        <Type>topic</Type>
                    </Item>
                    <Item>
                        <Title>Keep Your Heart Healthy</Title>
                        <Url>http://healthfinder.gov/HealthTopics/Category/health-conditions-and-diseases/heart-health/keep-your-heart-healthy</Url>
                        <Type>topic</Type>
                    </Item>
                </RelatedItems>
    this is the xmls file
```

Comment: What purpose will the rendered HTML fulfill? Answer to this question will allow me to give you the best suggestion at my disposal, based on what you're trying to do with your XML/HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to build the XSL. Here is a handy site to help you along the way:

http://www.w3schools.com/Xsl/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog_apply

and an excellent reference:

http://www.w3schools.com/Xsl/default.asp

Hope this helps.